# SDWebImage Caching to Memory but not to Disk

Tags: swift, sdwebimage

Still a newbie, so I am trying to learn! I have read previous questions on this topic, but they have all been older discussions. I am using SDWebImage to load images into my tableView. The images appear to be cached in memory because when I scroll through previous cells, the images are present instantly and do not download again. However, when I quit the app and re-open, all of the images appear to download again. I tried testing this by downloading the images, closing the app, turning on airplane mode, and opening app again. None of the images are present. The GitHub page implies that disk caching is automatic when entering the code below.

```
import SDWebImage
...
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell! {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

cell.myImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:imgURL!), placeholderImage: nil)
return cell
```

According to their documentation, this should be all I need. Is there something else I have to do to enable disk caching? I read about possibly putting something in the AppDelegate, but I have not done anything there.

Comment: According to the github example, you need to access a custom resource path (bundledPath) in the app delegate. Try that? https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/blob/master/Examples/SDWebImage%20Demo/AppDelegate.m

Comment: @Mocha none of that code snippet works if I place it into my AppDelegate

Comment: Doesn't works as in nothing changed, or it doesn't compile?

Comment: Doesn't compile due to errors. I don't know what to change since it's in objc

Comment: Convert it to swift.. For example here is the path. I don't know the methods used for adding the path. Play around with it. 


     _if let resourcePath = Bundle.main.resourcePath {
            let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: resourcePath).appendingPathComponent("CustomPathImages")
        }_